# Extending Hive partitioned ORC table breaks query

Tags: sql, hive, addition, alter, orc

I'm using Hive 3.0

I added a couple of columns to an ORC partitioned Hive internal table.
e.g.

```
create table test (a int) partitioned by ( b string) stored as ORC;
insert into test values(1,’a’);
insert into test values(2,’b’);
select * from test;
```

```
| test.a  | test.b  |
|---------|---------|
| 1       | a       |
| 2       | b       |
```

```
alter table test add columns (c string);
```

At the beginning I expect the values to be NULL in these columns.

```
select * from test;
```

```
| test.a  | test.c  | test.b  |
|---------|---------|---------|
| 1       | NULL    | a       |
| 2       | NULL    | b       |
```

When I perform a query with a where clause on the new columns the system breaks

```
select count(*) from test where c is null;
```

This generates an error

> Vertex did not succeed due to OWN_TASK_FAILURE, failedTasks:1
>   killedTasks:1, Vertex vertex_1579629597981_743514_1241_00 [Map 1]
>   killed/failed due to:OWN_TASK_FAILURE]Vertex killed,
>   vertexName=Reducer 2, vertexId=vertex_1579629597981_743514_1241_01,
>   diagnostics=[Vertex received Kill while in RUNNING state., Vertex did
>   not succeed due to OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE, failedTasks:0 killedTasks:1,
>   Vertex vertex_1579629597981_743514_1241_01 [Reducer 2] killed/failed
>   due to:OTHER_VERTEX_FAILURE]DAG did not succeed due to VERTEX_FAILURE.
>   failedVertices:1 killedVertices:1 (state=08S01,code=2)

I searched into the documentation but looks like I'm doing correctly.

Any suggestion?